# CorelDraw VBA Using variables in CQL

Tags: vba, variables, colors, cql, coreldraw

Guys Im Trying to use variables in my cql query

If I Use the following it works as expected and selects all the objects with the same cmyk color

```
ActivePage.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@fill.color = cmyk(100,0,0,0)").CreateSelection
```

I Want to use variables from an array that will find the color of one object and select all the other objects with the same color

I have tried the following

```
 Dim a, b, c, d
 a = 100
 b = 0
 c = 0
 d = 0
 ActivePage.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@fill.color = cmyk(a,b,c,d)").CreateSelection
```

when I do this i get the following error

identifier 'a' is not a member of global

any ideas what is going on

any help is appreciated

mark

Comment: Would appreciate any help please

Comment: You might need to escape the string so you can include the variables into the Query. Try something like `ActivePage.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@fill.color = cmyk(" & a & "," & b & "," & c & "," & d & ")").CreateSelection` and see if that gets you closer

Comment: you are a star thank you so much been racking my brains for a week on this

Comment: Added as an answer. Let me know if that solves it for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the answer to this one, is to escape the string, and concatenate the values into the query.

From the comments, this should work:

```
ActivePage.Shapes.FindShapes(Query:="@fill.color = cmyk(" & a & "," & b & "," & c & "," & d & ")").CreateSelection
```